# how to echo dynamic data inside php tag echo using php tags

Tags: php

```
<?php                   
    $i = 0;
    echo '<table>
        <tr>';
            foreach($Location as $value){
                $i++;
                echo '<td>'.$value->location.'</td>';
                    if($i == 6) { // three items in a row. Edit this to get more or less items on a row
                        echo '</tr><tr>';
                        $i = 0;
                        }
                    }
        echo '</tr>
    </table>';                  
?>
```

I want to show data in a table having 6 divisions i.e 6 td tag in a rows i.e tr tag
Data is showing in 6 td tag but i want to keep href tag i.e a tag using php tag
like

```
echo "<td> <a href="<?php echo 'geyser-' . str_replace(" ", "_", $value->location) ?>"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i><?php echo $value->location ?></a></td>";
```

showing ERROR. 
Anyone knows how to do? Thanks.

Comment: You can't open a PHP block inside a PHP block. Just do concatenation: `echo 'foo' . $bar . ' foobar';`